# How can I draw a pattern without using any third party libraries, and the sequence of input

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to draw a pattern in the image given below without using  any **libraries** in  python.

Input: 3 4 3 4 5 1 9 2 2 4

Image: [image]

Below is the code i tried but it does not working

```
def triangle(*args):
    main=[]
    for num in range(len(args)):
        k = args[num] - 1
        patt = []
        for i in range(0, args[num]):
            hello = ''
            for j in range(0, k):
                hello = hello + " "
            if num%2==0:
                k = k - 1
                hello = hello+"/"
            else:
                k = k+ 1
                hello = hello + "\\"
            patt.append(hello)
        main.append(patt)
    return main
lists = triangle(3,4,3)
```

Comment: Have you tried the Turtle library? It's part of the python standard library, i.e. you do not need to install anything else. See: https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Would you mind explaining what you mean by "not working"?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understand your question, but you could print it to the terminal without any modules.

In order to fit in bigger figures, you have to modify the length and amount of the rows. The lines don't connect perfectly, but you can definitely see the graph.

```py
number_input = [4, 3, 2, 2, 5]
# default pattern
pattern = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
           
height = 5 # starting row (adaptable)
rows = 14 # rows of the pattern
lines = 0 # lines added to the pattern

def figure(height, lines, nums):
    print(nums)
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        # if i is even it adds '/'
        if i % 2 == 0:
            for j in range(nums[i]):
                pattern[rows-height-1][lines] = '/'
                height += 1 # increase height by 1
                lines += 1 # count the lines added to the pattern
            height -= 1
        # if i is odd it adds '\'
        elif i % 2 == 1:
            for j in range(nums[i]):
                pattern[rows-height-1][lines] = '\\'
                height -= 1 # decrease height by 1
                lines += 1
            height += 1

figure(height, lines, number_input)

# replace zeros with spaces
for line in pattern:
    for i, num in enumerate(line):
        if num == 0:
            line[i] = ' '
    # print the lines
    print(*line)
```

Hope I could help.